# FInd values of $a, b$ such that $a < \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{1+e^{-f(x)}}dx < b$

Tags: calculus, integration

If $f(x)$ is **continuous** and $ln(3) < f(x) < ln(4) \forall x \in [0, 2]$. Then find values of $a, b$ such that $a < \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{1+e^{-f(x)}}dx < b$. Now this looks like a question where I should use the property $ln(3) (2) \leq \int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{1+e^{-f(x)}}dx \leq ln(4) (2)$ to solve for $a$ and $b$. There's a problem where there's a $e^{-f(x)}$ and it's hard to deal with that...Please tell me the next steps.

Comment: Hint: $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ is decreasing

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore could you explain? Sorry that I did not get the hint.